# Focus And Vertex Of An Inclined Parabola

Tags: conic-sections

How to find focus,vertex,directrix of a parabola like
$x^2+y^2+2xy-6x-2y+3=0$.
Well i know how to find those for any parabola of form $y^2=4ax$ but im just not being able to figure out a way to convert the given equation to this form. Help Please.

Comment: [Rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) the parabola, compute the focus, vertex, and directrix of the new figure, then apply the inverse rotation to them.

Comment: just a few more links explaining rotation of axes [here](http://math.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/document/show/2685) and [here](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Vectors/upfiles/RotationofAxes.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes)

Comment: Hey thank you both!i just now figured it out!!Thanks a ton!!The focus is (1,1),directrix as y=x+1 and vertex (3/4,5/4).